# How does LayerLimit in WMS capabilities work in QGIS 2.18.11?

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities

I set `<LayerLimit>1</LayerLimit>` in service metadata in capabilities file to restrict the number of layers that the client is permitted to request in a single GetMap request. But when I add a new WMS layer in QGIS, still I can select multiple layers simultaneously and multiple layers are requested coma separated ("`LAYERS=layer1,layer2,layer3`"). Does layer limit work differently? What is the correct way to restrict multiple layers request?

WMS version

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.3.0">
```

Comment: What software is providing the WMS service?

Comment: @nmtoken, I wrote a simple application in Python, it serves GetCapabilities and GetMap requests. It's based on Tornado. Geoprocessing is performed by means of GDAL + vsicurl

Comment: @nmtoken, I'm not sure that the service matters here. I'd like to discourage the user to request multiple layers (at the client side)

Comment: It's the server that sets the layer rule and responds to GetMap requests.  A client may not parse the layerlimit parameter in the capabilities response and give a standard GetMap request with multiple layers.  Just in the same way as a client is not meant to ask for CRS not advertised in the service, but can do so... it is up to the server to say no I don't support that CRS so I'm going to give an error.   So... If the server gives multiple layers on a GetMap request, even though it advertises that only one layer can be requested, then that is a server issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WMS 1.3.0 service implementations you can set a layer limit in the service metadata, how to do this varies on software.

For example in MapServer it is set in the MAP > WEB > METADATA section with  `"WMS_LAYERLIMIT" "8"`, and in the GetCapabilities response at location `/WMS_Capabilities/Service/LayerLimit` we have `<LayerLimit>8</LayerLimit>`.

If we look at the following GetMap requests (generated in QGIS) we can see the expected server behaviour to requests up to and beyond the layer limit.

Eight Layers requested (we get a map):

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/TFL-PSI/ows?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=32.51780000000000115,-9.379089999999999705,63.14789999999999992,37.84879999999999711&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=865&HEIGHT=561&LAYERS=ITA_Ancona4_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona4_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona3_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona3_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona2_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona2_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona1_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona1_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL&STYLES=,,,,,,,&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&

Nine layers requested (we get an error):

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/TFL-PSI/ows?language=eng&&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=32.51780000000000115,-9.379089999999999705,63.14789999999999992,37.84879999999999711&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=865&HEIGHT=561&LAYERS=GRC_Athens_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona4_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona4_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona3_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona3_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona2_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona2_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL,ITA_Ancona1_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS,ITA_Ancona1_ESA_EN_5k_psi_AvVEL&STYLES=,,,,,,,,&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&

```
<ServiceExceptionReport 
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="1.3.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
    <ServiceException>
    msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. 
    Number of layers requested exceeds LayerLimit.
    </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

So you are correct when you note that QGIS doesn't honour the advertised layer limit, this is technically a bug, because a client shouldn't request something that isn't advertised.

But your server is also at fault because it shouldn't provide something that the service provider (you) hasn't configured (even if the software is able to do so). People set limits on services for a reason...

Comment: thank you. Should I report an issue?

Comment: It's always worth reporting an issue